# Error decoding base64 string

Tags: java, base64

I have an XML file which have a node called "CONTENIDO", in this node I have a PDF file encoded in base64 string.

I'm trying to read this node, decode the string in base64 and download the PDF file to my computer.

The problem is that the file is downloaded with the same size (in kb)  as the original PDF and has the same number of pages, but... all the pages are in blank without any content and when I open the downloaded file a popup appears with an error saying "unknown distinctive 806.6n". I don't know what that means.

I've tried to find a solution in the internet, with diferents ways to decode the string, but always get the same result... The XML is Ok I've checked the base64 string and is Ok.
I've also debugged the code and I've seen that the content of the var "fichero" where I'm reading the base64 string is also Ok, so I don't know what can be the problem.

This is my code:

```
package prueba.sap.com;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class anexoPO {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         FileInputStream inFile =
              new FileInputStream("C:/prueba/prueba_attach_b64.xml");
         FileOutputStream outFile =
              new FileOutputStream("C:/prueba/salida.pdf");      
         anexoPO myMapping = new anexoPO();
         myMapping.execute(inFile, outFile);
         System.out.println("Success");
         System.out.println(inFile);         

    }

    public void execute(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
     throws com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException {

        try {       

          //************************Code To Generate The XML Parsing Objects*****************************//     
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = db.parse(in);
          Document docout = db.newDocument();

          NodeList CONTENIDO = doc.getElementsByTagName("CONTENIDO");
          String fichero = CONTENIDO.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

          //************** decode *************/

              //import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
              //BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
              //byte[] decoded = decoder.decodeBuffer(fichero);

              //import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;
              //byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(fichero);

              //import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
               byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(fichero);

          //************** decode *************/

          String str = new String(decoded);
          out.write(str.getBytes());

          } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.print("Problem parsing the file");
               e.printStackTrace();
              }       
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely:

```
out.write(decoded);
out.close();
```

Strings cannot represent all bytes, and PDF is binary.

Also remove the import of sun.misc.BASE64Decoder, as this package does not exist everywhere. It might be removed by the compiler, however I would not bet on it.